# Finding a beta of a regression from two regressions on distinct samples

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have observations for 10 years for the same variables but the computer can not run a regression with all observations appended.
Is there a way to find the final beta using each beta calculated in each regression by year?

in short, I would like to obtain `lm_tot` result using `lm_1` and `lm_2`

```
DT_1   <- data.frame(female=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0), salary=c(800,390,480,780,801,120,500), kids=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0))
DT_2   <- data.frame(female=c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0), salary=c(378,690,480,780,753,251,584), kids=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1))
DT_tot <- rbind(DT_1,DT_2) 

# regression by sex
  lm_1 <- lm(salary ~ female + kids, data=DT_1)
  print(lm_1)

  lm_2 <- lm(salary ~ female + kids, data=DT_2)
  print(lm_2)

  lm_tot <- lm(salary ~ female + kids, data=DT_tot)
  print(lm_tot)
```

Comment: I think you might be more likely to find someone with a good answer to this on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What happens if try to run the whole regression?

Comment: I suggest using either the mean value or median value for each fitted coefficient.